# Pausing a block of code from being run in google cloud functions/Dialogflow

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, pusher-js

I am using pusher to listen to a particular event being sent from another server.

I have successfully bind to the event but my problem is the code moves past the binding and executes the rest of the code.

I have tried using `Await` but that doesn't help also

I can't use `setTimeout` because the message to be received in the pusher event is determined by if the user completes payment.

The code

```
await pusher.bind(trans_id, function(data) {
        if (data.message === 'success') {
            agent.add('Transaction was successful');
        } else {
            agent.add('Transaction was unsuccessful');
        }
    });

    agent.add('Transaction Successful');

    console.log('We got here');
```

As you can see, the code is not waiting for the `pusher.bind` to execute, it jumps straight to the next `agent.add` and `console.log`

**Environment: Google Cloud Functions**

The code is for DialogFlow

Any help please

Comment: Please don't show screenshots of code.  It's better to copy the code into the question so it's easier to search and read.

Comment: I have removed the image @DougStevenson

Comment: which version of node.js you are using in firebase functions ? If version is Node 6 you can change the node version to 8 which is in beta right now or you can use babel to support async await in node 6.0

Comment: @AniketPawarI use 8... async await works already...

Answer (score 0):

Just continue your program logic inside the callback. `pusher.bind` finishes execution very quickly, it's the callback that gets executed later.

```
pusher.bind(trans_id, function(data) {
        if (data.message === 'success') {
            agent.add('Transaction was successful');
        } else {
            agent.add('Transaction was unsuccessful');
        }

        console.log('We got here');
    });
```